# $(AB) ^3=O_n$ and$(BA) ^3 \neq O_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A, B \in M_n(\mathbb C) $ so that $(AB) ^3=O_n$. Does this imply $(BA)^3=O_n$?.
I saw that the implication is true if $n\le 3$ and not true for $n\ge 4$. What I want is either a counterexample for $n\ge 4$ or some proof.( I can't find neither of them, I have tried using both HC and taking random matrices)

Comment: By $O_n$, do you mean the $n\times n$ zero matrix?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean by it.

Answer (score 4):

One classical counterexample is given by
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&1\\ &0&1\\ &&0&1\\ &&&0},
\ B=\pmatrix{1\\ &1\\ &&1\\ &&&0},
$$
so that $AB=J_3(0)\oplus0$ and $BA=A=J_4(0)$, where $J_k(0)$ denotes the $k\times k$ nilpotent Jordan block.

Comment: How did you come up with them?

Comment: @JustAnAmateur It's just a generalisation of the classical example of a pair of $(A,B)$ such that $AB=0$ but $BA\ne0$.

Comment: Thank you for your insight!